# Matplotlib - adjusting date spacing on the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data that looks like this:

`print x`

```
        Date       ABC       DEF
0 2004-06-03  1.000000  1.000000
1 2004-06-04  1.000000  1.007940
2 2004-06-07  1.000000  1.023285
3 2004-06-08  1.020163  1.024712
4 2004-06-09  1.013932  1.015166
```

And I am plotting it in the following way:

```
plt.figure()
x.plot().set_xticklabels(x['Date'])
plt.show()
```

My issue is that the x-axis ticks are too tight to be meaningful.

How would I get it such that every N-periods are shown on the x-axis?

Also - if you know the answer - how would I format the number on the x-axis to only be the date?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up finding another solution or lose interest in the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**: all comments in code have been added for clarification.

I'll show two examples to answer both questions.  I made a small csv from the sample data you posted.

Here is a plot just showing dates:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import math

# the sample data provided in the question was made into a csv and read in using pandas
data = pd.read_csv('Workbook1.csv', sep=',')
# get just the 'Date' column
dates = data['Date']

"""
datetime is a python module to work with dates, time, timezones, time differences

strptime(date_string, format) method is used to read in a string (which we know is
a date) and return a datetime. e.g.

>>> s = '2015-05-11'
>>> dt.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 11, 0, 0)

>>> print dt.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')
2015-05-11 00:00:00

>>> print dt.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
2015-05-11

list comprehension: a way to create a list

create a list of integers from 0 to 9:
>>> [x for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

create a list of 1/n! for n from 0 to 99 and sum the values:
>>> sum( [1.0/math.factorial(n) for n in xrange(100)] )
2.7182818284590455

below we use list comprehension to map date strings to datetimes in the 
specified format YYYY-MM-DD
"""
dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for d in dates]
```

Now the plotting:

```
""" 
we want to plot multiple data columns on one plot, so we use the layout 
manager subplots().  if we wanted to break out individual plots for each 
data source we could use subplots(n, m, o) where n,m,o are ints defining 
the layout.
figure is the window our plot will reside in
ax is used for nearly everything else: plot itself, labels, ticks, 
ticklabels, title(s)"""

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plot 'ABC' column, using red (r) line and label 'ABC' which is used in the legend
ax.plot(data['ABC'],'r-',label='ABC')
ax.plot(data['DEF'],'b-',label='DEF')
# set the number of ticks on x-axis to be a list [0, ... ,R]
# R is the number of rows in the data (i.e. len(dates))
# this ensures ticklabels align with the corresponding data point
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(dates))) 
ax.set_xticklabels(dates)     # set the ticklabels to the list of datetimes
ax.legend(loc=4, fontsize=10) # make a legend and place in bottom-right (loc=4)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)       # rotate the xticklabels by 30 deg
plt.show()
```

[image]

So this plot just shows the dates.  If this is still too cramped you can also change the date format to m/d/y and also possibly skip every Nth xticklabel.  Look at variable `spacing` and set as needed.

```
# using the list of datetimes from above make a list of strings with specific
# format.  datetime.strftime(format) returns a string in the specified format
short_dates = [d.strftime('%m/%d/%y') for d in dates]

spacing = 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data['ABC'],'r-',label="ABC")
ax.plot(data['DEF'],'b-',label='DEF')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(short_dates)))
ax.set_xticklabels(short_dates)
ax.legend(loc=4, fontsize=10)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
# for each label in the list of xticklabels 
# (we skip every n'th label in this list using [::n]):
# set to not visible
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::spacing]:
    label.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now the date format is changed and we are skipping every other date (from the given data). Hope this helps.

[This](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/htapia/scientific-python-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-4-Matplotlib.ipynb) is an excellent matplotlib tutorial.

Comment: Hey scott - i could not get this to work with my full data set and have instead opted to use d3, as it seems much more straight forward. Unfortunately I cannot post more of my data, and this method seems quite opaque unfortunately.

Comment: My answer is straightforward **if** you are familiar with matplotlib. If you are interested in understanding it I could comment each line, but if you got what you need from d3.js and don't plan to use matplotlib again then never mind. Matplotlib does have a difficult interface and not the most appealing defaults.

Comment: I really appreciate the offer. Let me generate a more constructive edit, and I will follow up. It's surprising how difficult each of the libraries is proving to be.

Comment: @jasonm I added some, hopefully useful, comments to explain whats going on.  I also linked a great tutorial full of examples.